# Select Iterate feature, use 2 Iterate rasters

Tags: raster

For multiple polygon data, I want to save the values ​​of multiple raster data that exist for each record for each record.

I have tried various things, and I have not been solved, so I ask a question.

1. I converted the polygon data into points and saved the raster values ​​using'Extract value to points' and'Extract multi values ​​to points'. The data is output horizontally, so I tried using'transpose fields', but the field I wanted was not created.
2. We tried to convert all raster data into pointer data, select one record of polygon data, and then save the points included in the area. In this case, the point data was made into one shp through'merge'. It is possible for a small area, but data was not generated when shp exceeded 2Gb.

The process I want to do is as follows.
I have raster data and and vector data.
1000 raster data are stored in the'img' folder, and the format is *.img.

The vector data is polygon and there are 1000 pieces.

The model builder was planned by writing the following scenario. Image reference

1. I select the first record (ex. eco1) from the grid data. And it creates the'aaa' field.
2. Read the raster data stored in the'img' folder one by one using'iterate rasetr'.
3. Read the raster data of 2. included in the record area selected in 1. and save it in the'aaa' field of 1.
4. After reading all raster files, eco1 saves them as shp files.
5. Next, repeat steps 2-4 after selecting eco2.

[image]

Questions
Various attempts are made, but failure occurs.
I want to get help on how to approach it.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  Your "model builder" does not look like the ModelBuilder of either ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap.

Comment: The figure is shown as an example. What I used is an arcgis map.

Comment: By "arcgis map" do you mean ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Both have their own ModelBuilder.